# Uninstalling pillow requires another 161 packages to be removed

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I'm using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 with Python 3.7.4 and accoding to conda list I have pillow 6.2.0 installed, which should be fine. However I cannot import it in a project, neither using `import pillow`, nor `import PIL`. I tried to update it to no avail, I did a `conda update pillow`, but this didn't help. Now I'm trying to `conda uninstall pillow`, however it tells me then that another 161 (!) packages will be removed, among which anaconda-navigator-1.9.7-py37_0, anaconda-client-1.7.2-py37_0, matplotlib-3.1.3-py37_0,jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7 etc...

This does not sound right! What shall I do? Completely uninstall Anaconda or trying to force removing only the specific pillow package?

EDIT: When trying to remove the pillow package via the Anaconda GUI, it throws the error: "Downgrading/removing these packages will modify Anaconda Navigator dependencies."

EDIT: `help('modules')` returns that package `pil` is installed, indeed `import pil` works. matplotlib though seems to not recognize it??

Comment: What happens when you call `which python`?

Comment: I'm running it on Windows, but ```where python``` returns ...\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe. It should be the correct python interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a workaround: Since apparently the module is installed as `pil` and `matplotlib` is looking for `PIL`, I modified the image.py file in the matplotlib folder of the package. Instead of `import PIL` I changed it to `import pil`. Now the code runs without errors!